# POST request with mobile number not working - message: "The Mobile Number field is required.↵"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, httpclient, angular8

M getting response from server: `{status: false, message: "The Mobile Number field is required.↵"}`

```
 submitForm() {
    this.createItem(this.data).subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        console.log(this.data)
    });
 }
```

this function calls a function to send mobile number

```
  createItem(data): Observable<MobileNo> {
    console.log(`data = ` ,JSON.stringify(data))
    return this.httpClient
      .post<MobileNo>(this.base_path, JSON.stringify(data), this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        retry(2),
        catchError(this.handleError),
      )
  }
```

Function to Post data

```
 export class MobileNo {
    ext : string;
    mobile_no :string;
 }
```

MobileNo Class

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Edit Student Data</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">mobile</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" #todo id="name" [(ngModel)]="data.mobile_no" placeholder="Enter No">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="age">ext</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="age" [(ngModel)]="data.ext" placeholder="Enter 91">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="submitForm()">Update</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning ml-1" [routerLink]="[ '/welcome']">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Form to submit number

what i am doing wrong here i have no idea

Comment: Replace `JSON.stringify(data)` with `data`.

Comment: Cross check you payload is what is expected by the server. This clearly is a server validation error.. The server is not getting the data as it expects it to be.

Comment: @Maryannah same response, tried replacing JSON.stringify(data) with data, not working

Comment: What do you get from `console.log(\`data = \` ,JSON.stringify(data))`?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri m getting  data =  {"mobile_no":9673132365,"ext":91}

Comment: Could you also check the `network` tab in Chrome DevTools if the body of the POST contains this data?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri i think server is expecting formdata and m sending json